# upgrade AWS HVM Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, server, upgrade, 20.04, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS HVM AMI running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to upgrade to 20.04 LTS.

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Seems to work as expected. Completes the upgrade up to the reboot at the end. Once the system reboots, it never comes back. And Amazon EC2 doesn't know there is a problem, reporting the instance is continuing to run with system checks passing. The upgrade is vanilla. I choose to install grub onto the / boot partition. And I choose to keep my own modified sshd configuration file. Also keep the cloud-init configuration from the 18.04 system software.

Back in 2018, I created this AMI starting with the free Ubuntu HVM compatible AWS AMI running 18.04 LTS. This was a messy process, because I had to add my own volume based file systems. My intuition tells me this upgrade failure may be related to this history. I suspect Ubuntu needs to clean up their support for AWS HVM systems. No one should have to go through this just to run their own HVM compatible AMI on AWS. Although I would be happy to learn of an easier solution than having to derive a new AWS HVM 20.04 LTS AMI.

In the end, I have to execute an EC2 instance termination and lose the upgraded system. Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like on Virtulization level instance instance is healthy but could be problem in network. Did you try to access system via console ?

Comment: @Karen did you ever find an answer to this?